VS Code Live Server extension opens the debugger in Chrome dev tools first when saving changes instead of printing to the console right away
Every time I save my file using cmd + s shortcut key to reflect the changes on live server, the debugger in Chrome dev tools always opens, and unless I hit the play button, that's the only time my code will be printed to the console. This has only happened recently and I do not know how to fix it.
I tried to uninstall and reinstall the live server extension but it still behave the same.
